# Looking for an old first-person-shooter

Tags: game

No sure this is the right place to ask; let me know if not and where else to ask...

Anyway, I am looking for an old first-person-shooter (maybe 20 years old, PC), you were shooting just some kind of monsters, not humans, and the entire play was within a closed building. Gameplay was very easy, and you have to achieve some goal to get to the next level (literally the next level), in order to prevent someone lifting up with a spaceship(?).

If you have some idea, please let me know, I then can google images from the game. Thanks.

Addendum:

- I think the game has speech in it, and probably one catch-phrase is "you will never succeed"...

Comment: https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/818/is-software-identification-on-topic

Answer (score 2):

[Blake Stone: Aliens of Gold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blake_Stone:_Aliens_of_Gold) ? You are in some building and you have to get keycards to enable the use of the elevators to go to the next level

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

I played Doom more than 25 years ago. It was my first 1st person shooter. Also more than 20 years ago was Duke Nukem and Wolfenstein. Wolfenstein may be more too your liking since it occurs in one building with multiple rooms. You shoot nazi's so I hope thats ok. Good luck on finding these vintage computer games.

Comment: I really don't think the game I am looking for is 'doom'...

Comment: Some of us still have our original installer disks for Doom and the original classic Quake ... :)

Comment: @Alex I misinterpreted your question.  I thought you were looking for games in general.  I now understand you are looking for a particular game.  Sorry for my confusion.